# How to change parent value with using child value VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I need to change the value of Total which is found in the parent component. It will change from child component values.

```
<!--Parent Component-->
<template>
  <div class="section__wrapper">
      <h1>Total:{{ this.total }}</h1>
      <vItem title="First Item" price=2 @clicked="onClickChild"></vItem>
      <vItem title="Second Item" price=3  @clicked="onClickChild"></vItem>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import vItem from './v-item.vue';
export default {
   data(){
      return{
         total:1000000,
      }
   },
   components: {
      vItem
  }
}
</script>


<!--Child Component-->
<template>
  <div class="item__body">
   <div class="item__body__content">
      <img src="" alt="" class="item__body__content__img">
      <p>{{ this.totalOfItem }}</p>
      <p class="item__body__content__title">{{ this.title }}</p>
      <p class="item__body__content__price">{{ this.price }}</p>
      <div class="item__body__content__control">
         <button class="item__body__content__btn sell" @click="increasePrice">sell</button>
         <input type="text" class="item__body__content__input" :value=this.count>
         <button class="item__body__content__btn buy" @click="decreasePrice">buy</button>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
   props: {
    title: String,
    price: Number,

  },
  data(){
   return{
      count:0,
      totalOfItem: 0
   }
  },
  methods:{
   increasePrice(){
      this.count -= 1
      this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
   },
   decreasePrice(){
      this.count += 1
      this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
   },

  }
}
</script>
```

I need a method that reduces the total as the number of different products. The problem is that writing such a method for a single product is not difficult, but for several products it is a bit difficult for me. Each item has a price and quantity.

Comment: You can use vue events to send data and trigger a function  on parent https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Comment: i know how to pass data, i cant correctly decrease total in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vuejs emits: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html.

Try somthing like this on your child component:

```
export default {
   props: {
    title: String,
    price: Number,
  },
  data(){
   return{
      count:0,
      totalOfItem: 0
   }
  },
  emits: ['onClickChild'],
  setup(props, emit) {
   function increasePrice(){
      this.count -= 1
      this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
      emit('onClickChild', this.totalOfItem)
   }

   function decreasePrice(){
      this.count += 1
      this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
      emit('onClickChild', this.totalOfItem)
   }
   
   return {
      increasePrice,
      decreasePrice,
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: THX, but i know how to pass data, i cant correctly decrease total in parent component. Can u help?

Comment: <!--Parent component-->
methods:{
onClickChild(value){
   this.total -= value
}
   
<!--Child component-->
methods:{
increasePrice(){
   this.count -= 1
   this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
   this.$emit('clicked', this.totalOfItem)
},
decreasePrice(){
   this.count += 1
   this.totalOfItem = this.count * this.price
   this.$emit('clicked', this.totalOfItem)
}
}